# Show a div when a link with a class is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am wanting to show/fadein a `<div>` with an ID of "signInHold" when the `<li>` "Sign In" is clicked using the class signInActive on the `<li>`.

```
<ul class="nav1">
    <li class="nav2">
        <a href="http://rocketcss.com" class="nav2">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav2">
        <a href="http://rocketcss.com/settings" class="nav2">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav2">
        <a href="http://rocketcss.com/download" class="nav2">Download</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav2 signInActive">
        <a href="http://rocketcss.com/download" class="nav2">Sign In</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could you please also tell me if I need to add:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery, you probably have to add it. Otherwise, you don't ?

Comment: highly advise against using the latest jquery. use a specific version to avoid potential breakage in the future.

Comment: `<div> named "signInHold"` is this ID or class?

Comment: @RickViscomi ID, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: TymeJV's post helped, but how do I make the #signInHold hidden as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery (in the head)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#signInHold").hide();
      $(".signInActive").click(function() {
          $("#signInHold").fadeToggle("slow"); <--This targets the div with ID signInHold
      });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you call out jQuery in the head?

Comment: @tymeJV thanks, this seemed to work, but the problem I have now is to make the `#signInHold` hidden as default.

Comment: @tymeJV `$("#signInHold").hide().fadeToggle("slow");` this had no change.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery, or you can do it with straight CSS using the `transition` property; it's entirely up to you and the needs of your project.

jQuery will give you far better cross-browser support:

```
$(".nav1").on("click", ".signInActive", function () {
    $(".bar").fadeIn();
});
```

Or, you could do it with CSS:

```
.foo {
    opacity: 0;
}

.foo.activated {
    transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And simply toggle the class:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".signInActive");
var target  = document.querySelector(".myDIV");

element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    target.classList.toggle("activated");
}, false);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add "activated" to the clicked element, not the div?

Comment: @RickViscomi It will add it to whatever `target` is. Note, this isn't `event.target`.

Comment: Shouldn't the transition be on `.foo` instead of `.foo.activated`

Comment: @Musa It's up to the user. I put it on the `.activated` state so that it will hide instantly, and fade in slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.signInActive').click(function () { $('#signInHold').show(); });
```

This assumes you do load jQuery, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add jquery 
Add the class signIn to your li and now when you click the div will appear 
and the class signInActive added to you

```
<li class="nav2 signIn">
 <a href="http://rocketcss.com/download" class="nav2">Sign In</a>
</li>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.signIn').click(function(){
    $('#signInHold').fadeIn(300);
    $(this).addClass('signInActive');
  });
});
```